# Cleaning pressure cookers advice

Tags: cleaning, pressure-cooker

So, I'm not too sure if there's a stack website that talks about cleaning but I figure I can ask the experts chefs!

I wanted to cook some rice in my pressure cooker earlier and when I opened my lid, I saw a bunch of small flies coming out and around the pressure cooker! It was really gross and I've been using it alot recently!

Anyways, I realized that all this time, I should have been cleaning the pressure cooker and not just the removable pot. So my question is, does anyone know how to clean a pressure cooker fully? I was thinking of submerging it in a tub of water mixed with some bleach and letting it dry few a week or so. Let me know, thanks.

Also - I have one of those pressure cookers with a heating unit in it and I've been using it for the past two years without cleaning it (except of course the removable pot).

Comment: You're talking about something like an electric pressure cooker combo unit, right?  Something with a programmable heating element in the base, a removable insert, and a locking lid with a pressure valve?

Comment: If you know it, you're more than welcome to post the brand/model of your cooker.

Comment: @logophobe yes, it is exactly what you described

Comment: @catija and I think this is the model - it looks almost identical to the picture (https://usa.tiger-corporation.com/01ricecooker/10-jnp-electric-rice-cooker.html)

Comment: I don't know anything about this model, but the instructions sheet on the link you gave says explicitly NOT to immerse the whole unit in water (which is generally good advice for electrical appliances, unless the instructions say you can). I'd say the best course of action is to find where the flies were coming from, whether there's spilled food or something there, etc., and trying to wipe it out as best as possible with a damp cloth or something, maybe a small brush if necessary (e.g., to get into a small crevice).

Comment: Aluminum and bleach are **not** friends. The high pH of bleach will cause aluminum to corrode. Looks like your cooker has a steel pot. If nonstick, I'd still avoid bleach, as it's likely to make pre-existing coating damage worse.

Answer (score 1):

Well to clean the pressure cooker,Immediately after use, fill the pressure cooker with warm water and add a small amount of washing up liquid, and allow it to soak for an hour or two hours. This prevents any cooked food from becoming embedded around the inner regions of the cooker .
Then wash the pressure cooker by running it under hot water and using a cloth or a sponge and apply some washing up liquid cleaner. Rinse the cooker and dry it, using a dishcloth, to ensure that no excess water is left that could cause water stains.This way you can clean the cooker after daily use.

But to remove permanent stains you can use cream of tartar which is a spice along with lemon juice.
To that boil one litre of water in a container by adding 3 tablespoon of cream of tartar and 3 tablespoon of lemon juice. And pour this solution to the pressure cooker and allow it to stand for an hour or two.

Then using a plastic scouring pad or sponge clean the pressure cooker, avoid the metal pad as it might damage the cooker.

Hope it might help you and enjoy cooking.